# conditional comments in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-11, conditional-comments

I am trying to use SVG icons from an SVG sprite as DIV background. I have PNG icons to fallback for browsers that don't support SVG. This works with Chrome and Firefox but not IE11 (and Safari). IE11 renders SVG images but not as background of DIV in CSS. IE10 and IE11 don't accept conditional comments. I tried to add X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=9') but it does not help.
I am looking for a way to have SVG Icons from a "Sprite" and PNG for older browsers. How can this be done without JS? Is there a workaround?

Comment: There must be something else going on here.  IE and Safari both support SVG as background images.  Are you using data URIs?  Do your SVG files display on their own?  Is it a scaling issue?  If the browser didn't support SVG at all, it would automatically fallback to the previous background image declaration.

Comment: As base64 I managed to inline into "background-image" in the CSS and it works with all browsers. If instead of base64 I paste the SVG Code it does not work. I prefer SVG over base 64 as it's shorter, more legible, can be manipulated, and has no size limit.

Comment: Yes, IE doesn't support plain-text data URIs.  You need to either URL encode or base64 encode.

Comment: You should still be able to use normal fallback rules: `div {background: url(fallback.png); background: url('data:image/svg+xml,...')`.  If the browser has an error reading the data URI it should fallback to the PNG.  If you have to set position, do so within the shorthand `background` declaration.

Comment: Escaping URL code as background image is also partially supported. I found: background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,<svg\ version=\"1.1\"\ xmlns=\"http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg\"\ width=\"32px\"\ height=\"32px\"\ viewBox=\"0\ 0\ 32\ 32\"><circle\ fill=\"red\"\ cx=\"16\"\ cy=\"16\"\ r=\"12\"/></svg>);
working in all browsers. In this code spaces are replaced with \ and some other changes. Online tools convert everything and the resultant code does not work for URI. I did not get to the conversion rule and didn't find a coder that will produce such working code.